# Mysql Database Design A Complex Shopping Catalogue Part

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I want to make an anouncement system. But i messed the database design part.

The system will have unlimited categories and their items so every category will has strange properties

for example car has a model, trade, manufacture date, color, gear type. . . and more

another example Real Estate has a door count, gardened, dublex triplex type, how many bath, how many kitchen

another one can be electronic, it has megapixel, gigabyte, warrantie, resolution, dimensions, shipment . . .

so how i can collect these datas together maybe some objects will have similar properties for example most of items must have a manufacter date so how i can use the datas ? How can be the schema ?

Sercan Virlan

Comment: Is there a definite list of categories, or could someone decide they want to add a category with arbitrary properties at any time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind you, this is a very vague question, so I am trying my best to answer :)

Note: There are many better ways to do this, and I could question WHY you are doing it this way, but the below method should accomplish what you are looking for!

Here are 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `object` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`category` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `properties` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`objectid` INTEGER NOT NULL ,
`property_key` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
`property_value` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `category` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Now lets add some pretend data into them:

```
INSERT INTO category VALUES ("","CAR");
INSERT INTO category VALUES ("","REALESTATE");
INSERT INTO category VALUES ("","ELECTRONIC");
INSERT INTO object VALUES ("",1,"98 CAMERO");
INSERT INTO object VALUES ("",1,"06 PRIUS");
INSERT INTO object VALUES ("",2,"A House Someplace");
INSERT INTO object VALUES ("",3,"iPod Touch");
INSERT INTO object VALUES ("",3,"iPhone");
INSERT INTO object VALUES ("",3,"Zune");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",1,"color","red");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",1,"doors","4");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",1,"engine","v6");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",2,"engine","electric");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",2,"doors","4");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",2,"color","blue");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",6,"video-playback","true");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",4,"video-playback","true");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",5,"video-playback","true");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",6,"manufacturer","microsoft");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",5,"manufacturer","apple");
INSERT INTO properties VALUES ("",4,"manufacturer","apple");
```

Now, here is what our data should look like.

```
mysql> select * from object;
+----+----------+-------------------+
| id | category | name              |
+----+----------+-------------------+
|  1 |        1 | 98 CAMERO         | 
|  2 |        1 | 06 PRIUS          | 
|  3 |        2 | A House Someplace | 
|  4 |        3 | iPod Touch        | 
|  5 |        3 | iPhone            | 
|  6 |        3 | Zune              | 
+----+----------+-------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from category;
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | CAR         | 
|  2 | REALESTATE  | 
|  3 | ELECTRONICS | 
+----+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from properties;
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+
| id | objectid | property_key   | property_value |
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 | color          | red            | 
|  2 |        1 | doors          | 4              | 
|  3 |        1 | engine         | v6             | 
|  4 |        2 | engine         | electric       | 
|  5 |        2 | doors          | 4              | 
|  6 |        2 | color          | blue           | 
|  7 |        6 | video-playback | true           | 
|  8 |        4 | video-playback | true           | 
|  9 |        5 | video-playback | true           | 
| 10 |        6 | manufacturer   | microsoft      | 
| 11 |        5 | manufacturer   | apple          | 
| 12 |        4 | manufacturer   | apple          | 
+----+----------+----------------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can add an unlimited number of categories, an unlimited number of properties, and an unlimited number of objects all into these tables.

Now to join them ALL together:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM object 
    ->   LEFT JOIN category ON object.category = category.id
    ->   LEFT JOIN properties ON properties.objectid = object.id;
+----+----------+-------------------+------+-------------+------+----------+----------------+----------------+
| id | category | name              | id   | name        | id   | objectid | property_key   | property_value |
+----+----------+-------------------+------+-------------+------+----------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 | 98 CAMERO         |    1 | CAR         |    1 |        1 | color          | red            | 
|  1 |        1 | 98 CAMERO         |    1 | CAR         |    2 |        1 | doors          | 4              | 
|  1 |        1 | 98 CAMERO         |    1 | CAR         |    3 |        1 | engine         | v6             | 
|  2 |        1 | 06 PRIUS          |    1 | CAR         |    4 |        2 | engine         | electric       | 
|  2 |        1 | 06 PRIUS          |    1 | CAR         |    5 |        2 | doors          | 4              | 
|  2 |        1 | 06 PRIUS          |    1 | CAR         |    6 |        2 | color          | blue           | 
|  3 |        2 | A House Someplace |    2 | REALESTATE  | NULL |     NULL | NULL           | NULL           | 
|  4 |        3 | iPod Touch        |    3 | ELECTRONICS |    8 |        4 | video-playback | true           | 
|  4 |        3 | iPod Touch        |    3 | ELECTRONICS |   12 |        4 | manufacturer   | apple          | 
|  5 |        3 | iPhone            |    3 | ELECTRONICS |    9 |        5 | video-playback | true           | 
|  5 |        3 | iPhone            |    3 | ELECTRONICS |   11 |        5 | manufacturer   | apple          | 
|  6 |        3 | Zune              |    3 | ELECTRONICS |    7 |        6 | video-playback | true           | 
|  6 |        3 | Zune              |    3 | ELECTRONICS |   10 |        6 | manufacturer   | microsoft      | 
+----+----------+-------------------+------+-------------+------+----------+----------------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I hope this is what you are looking for, its an infinitely scalable solution, though if the database becomes incredibly taxed with a heavy workload, it could slow down, just due to its design.

Comment: thanks for your reply

there was a little info that i forget to mention about it i must use these values on forms 

and forms must have checkboxes input boxes selectboxes etc. so how i must group the values with form elements for a category to show its form ?